# C# How to Make a Custom Dashboard Using Visual Studio Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, widget, dashboard

I want to make a custom dashboard that will take the data I have in SQL Server and display it. Below is a general example of what I'd like to make. It's not going look exactly like this.

This project is being built in Visual Studio in a Window Forms Application and is being written in C#.

[image: Example Picture - Click Here]

**What I need to know is:**

1. How can I get a range of custom widgets like arrows, gauges, timelines, etc?
2. Do I need to download a .dll or something?
3. Where would I go to get something like this? (Preferably for free, but I'm not opposed to paying a little for something good.)

Any help you can give would be useful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well the arrows arent necessarily widgets, they can be just pictures, same as the little men.  So, the only thing you're really looking at there are bargraphs, and the half pie charts.. there is a charting tool built in, but I dont think it does half pie charts... what did you try so far?

Comment: This is just a general visual description of what I would like to build. What I'm looking for is widgets. Any widgets will do for now. How do I get these?

Comment: What pictures? try google images.. steal them from the mock up you showed us.. the chart tool is already in VS

Comment: I can't just get this stuff from Google Images and slap it in my project. Those pictures are static. The whole idea of the dashboard is that the image changes along with the data. Thus, you need a widget.

Comment: No, but you have arrows, you know you could like colour them, and move them, you have people by the looks of it, you need 2 imagines 1 green, 1 red.. so yes you can..

Answer (score 1):

The term "widget" isn't natural lingo for Windows Forms as it was for X11. What you are looking for are called Controls in the WinForms world, and there are lots of places to get them for free or paid.

The Control library I am looking into right now is from [SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/). It looks expensive, but if you are a 5-person (or smaller) development shop, they give you their entire product line for free. If you are a larger group than that, there are free sources for Controls that I can help you find. Many of them are here in StackOverflow. Try searching for "control" or "control library".